# Dead Rising 2: Mix Matching

Tags: dead-rising-2

With the Dead rising 2 DLC (Soldier, Psycho, etc.) Do you have to wear the full outfit for the effects to work or can you mix and match and have all of them at one? I am fond of soldiers appearance but I would like to wield all the abilities of the DLC at once. So is it or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible and it does work but there is a small caveat.** According to [the Dead Rising wikia](http://deadrising.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Rising_2_Skill_Packs), as long as you wear one piece of any of these DLC outfits, their effects can be combined with the possible exception of some funniness with the Ninja and Off The Record where only one bonus works at a time (bolding is mine):

> ### Ninja
>
> - When Chuck wears just one piece of the outfit, it unlocks new abilities in Chuck associated with the Ninja theme. When all 4 pieces of the outfit are worn, additional Ninja-like animations are also unlocked!...
> - Stealth: While wearing any part of the outfit Chuck is nearly undetectable to standard zombies. Psychopaths and Gas Zombies can detect you normally however.
> - **Wearing all pieces (Some players can wear just one piece of the outfit but this may only work sometimes)** unlocks a superior set of attacks while using (specified) weapons...Stacked throwing items (Nails, Plates, Gems, CDs, etc.) will also do more damage and Chuck’s throwing speed is increased.
>
> ...
>
> ### Notes
>
> - **The outfits can be combined (NOT in Off The Record. Only one bonus suit works at a time there). As long as you wear at least one item from either of the four outfits, you can combine them to make Chuck the ultimate zombie slayer.**